# How to flter XML BI Publisher report in RTF Template

Tags: bi-publisher

How do I combine filter conditions in an RTF Template?

Desired filter condition:

```
APPLICATION=('AC','LD')
AND 
CATEGORY=('1001','1002')
```

I tried using `<?for-each-group:G_1[contains(category,'1001')];./grouping_element?>`, but it is filtering with only one condition.

Comment: Early i Used <?for-each-group:G_1[contains(category,'1001')];./grouping_element?>,But It Filtering Only with one value

Comment: Post your xml also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AND and OR in the standard filters.

```
<?for-each-group:G_1[(category="1001" or category="1002") and (application="LD" or application ="AC")];./grouping_element?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer Below & change accordingly,

```
<?for-each:G_MAIN?><?if@row:(contains(TASK_NUMBER,'-00-000') or contains(TASK_NUMBER,'0000'))?>
```